# Conditional statement not working as intended

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following code which is supposed to first check the `navigator.platform`, and if the user is coming to the page from a device other than an iPhone or iPad, redirect to the given page. However, it is currently redirecting iPad and iPhone devices to that page.

```
    var param = document.location.search.split("?link=");

//IF DEVICE IS NOT IPHONE, REDIRECT USER TO OTHER PLATFORM PAGE
    if (navigator.platform != 'iPhone' || navigator.platform != 'iPad')
    {
        window.location.replace("other-platform.html");
    }

    else if(param[1] === 'faq-link' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad' )
    {
        window.location.replace("#");
    }

    else if (param[1] === 'footer-link' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad')
    {
        window.location.replace("#");
    }

    else if(param[1] === 'share-page-A-getapp' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad')
    {
        window.location.replace("#");
    }

    else if(param[1] === 'share-page-B-getapp' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad')
    {
        window.location.replace("#");
    }

    else if(param[1] === 'share-page-C-getapp' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad')
    {
        window.location.replace("#");
    }
```

Comment: Last 3 words, fine. First word: a bit much. He's got 200 karma, probably a new programmer. Be nicer.

Comment: The last three words convey that a switch would also be a nice thing, possibly.  The first word conveys that the existing code is disgusting and that Matt should leap for a switch like a drowning man for a float.  Sufficient niceness will have Matt proudly showing this to a prospective employer as an example of his excellent JavaScript chops.  A little bit of treating him like an adult in the company of adults, that would be actually nicer in the long run.

Comment: Well since the code in each alternative does exactly the same thing, I don't think a `switch` would make it much better anyway. It could be a regex or an array of possible values, and just one `else if`.

Comment: Aside from the first comment being un-constructive, I'm not a new programmer either. Haven't had much coffee or sleep, and will admit the code is pretty ugly. To the point though, the problem at its basic form: if the user is NOT coming from an iPhone or iPad, redirect to a page called `other-platform.html`. Otherwise, if the query parameter is one of the following and the user is coming from an iPhone or iPad, redirect to the corresponding link (each of the window.location.replace links goes to a different place, but links have been removed for the example).

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing 
if (navigator.platform != 'iPhone' || navigator.platform != 'iPad') to 
if (navigator.platform != 'iPhone' && navigator.platform != 'iPad')

I could make it prettier with a switch statement later on.

Comment: Since this is what @Pointy pointed out, I'd assume you're going to accept that answer.

Comment: @Matt I'm glad you got things working better, but note that my answer explains why all your `else if` clauses are also incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the logic here:

```
if (navigator.platform != 'iPhone' || navigator.platform != 'iPad')
```

If `navigator.platform` **is** equal to "iPhone", then it's *not* equal to "iPad". If it is equal to "iPad", it's not equal to "iPhone". The `if` test is therefore always `true` because all strings are either not equal to "iPhone" or else not equal to "iPad".

The `||` should be `&&`.

Subsequently, your tests that involve `'iPhone' || 'iPad'` are not doing what you think. Take the first one:

```
else if (param[1] === 'faq-link' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad' )
```

We can add parentheses to show how JavaScript interprets the expression:

```
else if (((param[1] === 'faq-link') && (navigator.platform === 'iPhone')) || 'iPad' )
```

That is, it compares `param[1]` to the string "faq-link" first. If that succeeds, then it compares `navigator.platform` to the string "iPhone". If that also succeeds, then the test is true. However, if one of those two tests fails, the other side of the `||` operator is the string constant `'iPad'`, and that will always be interpreted as `true`.  Thus, each one of those comparison clauses also has an always-true condition.

To fix those, all you need to do is get rid of the tests for "iPhone" and "iPad", because once you fix the very first test as described above, the other tests can safely assume that `navigator.platform` is either "iPhone" nor "iPad". So that test would be just:

```
else if (param[1] === 'faq-link')
```

Comment: One answer that addresses the dominant problem. What about the switch idea (comment on question) to further simplify?

Comment: @BillWoodger sure, using a switch would be good, or since every alternative does exactly the same thing, just checking a list or a map to see if `param[1]` is one of the looked-for values.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error on your if conditions, the last one:
For example, 
    (param[1] === 'faq-link' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad') 
should be
    (param[1] === 'faq-link' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || navigator.platform === 'iPad').

Also best to group conditions with additional parentheses for clarity, i.e,
    ( (param[1] === 'faq-link') && (navigator.platform === 'iPhone') ||  (navigator.platform === 'iPad') )

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

```
 else if(param[1] === 'faq-link' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad' )
will allways return true because 'iPad' is true.
```

change like that:

```
 else if(param[1] === 'faq-link' && navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || navigator.platform ==='iPad' )
```